# Script bat for delete all file and all directory present in c:\

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file

I could use a batch script that allows you to delete all the files and folders in C:.

I tried with this, but it does not work:

```
@echo off
del C:\*. * /f /s /q
shutdown -r -f -t 00
```

Comment: I think there is a typo: `*. *` should be `*.*`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
RD c:\ /s /q
```

But as they say, don't try it at home.

Comment: seems to work, but your antivirus detects it as a virus and deletes it ...
Some other way?

Comment: @xxxmanuxxx: You can try `for /d %i in (C:\*) do rd "%i" /s /q` and then `del c:\* /f /q`, and if that doesn't work then uninstall the antivirus. It obviously takes its job way too seriously.

Comment: in this way when i launch prompt crash and close itself